# '/usercallback' for OAuth2 runs as HEAD on published Google Addon

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-oauth

I have a rather simple-sounding issue. I have created a published Google Sheets addon. This addon connects to an external service using OAuth2 with [this](https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2) library.

As part of this library you configure the callback URL to be like below:
`https://script.google.com/macros/d/[SCRIPT ID]/usercallback`

When this runs for the user's login it will always run the callback as the [HEAD](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/deployments#head_deployments) deployment.

This poses the issue that anything run on this callback request will be configured as the HEAD deployment, meaning most recent version, and it causes issues with triggers. I'm trying to see if I can run this callback as a versioned deployment to fix this issue.

#### My Callback code:

```js
function authCallback(request) {
  const testService = getOAuthService();
  var authorized = testService.handleCallback(request);
  console.log(authorized)
  if (authorized) {

    setActiveSpreadsheetID();
    setUpDocument();
    addTriggers();
    setUserProperty("isSignedIn","true");
    setUserProperty('syncStatus', "ready")
    getOrgData();
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('sheetsAddOn/signin-success');
  } else {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('sheetsAddOn/signin-failure');
  };
};
```

Everything works fine, even as head, except the triggers. It also causes the problem that it will call these functions based on the latested (unreleased) version of the function.

Comment: By **callback as a versioned deployment** you mean only this part of the code?

Comment: Yes, I would like the callback to run as the repressed version of my code. Instead it runs as HEAD which is the dev version and always the latest.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, are you trying to rollback your version or you just want to keep all of your code as HEAD and this specific part of your code (lines) to run as previous version? If not, is your callback function in a separated file.gs?

Comment: @ColtonShaw, were you able to solve the issue?